# how can set media play controller in layout?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mpmediaplayercontroller

how can set media play controller in layout?

when I slider the recycleview, the media play controller cannot hold in layout, how can setting it?

Answer (score 0):

In RecyclerView Adapter 1) Initialize the context

```
`    private var context: Context? = null
```

`

2. Then pass the context with parent in onCreateViewHolder

   `

   ```
    context=parent.context
   ```

`

3)set the mediacontroller in BindViewHolder along with context

```
 ` val mediaController = MediaController(context);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.video11);
   holder.video11.setMediaController(mediaController);
    holder.video11.start()`
```

Comment: `    private var context: Context? = null,   how could change to java?

Comment: Not a complicated one.. " Val " is just used to assign a variable

Comment: now I had public Context mContext in Adapter, so I need to set mContext = null? then in fragment how could I do?

Comment: 1)You can place your media controller in adpter of your recycler view fragment ust follow the above codes..

Comment: I use this code, public Context mContext = null; ,mContext = parent.getContext(); and mediaController = new MediaController(mContext);, it's still problem